How to conduct temperature variant EM simulations in HFSS?
I want to conduct temperature variant EM simulations in HFSS i.e. simulate s parameters of a CPW at various temperatures. I am using a temperature variant material using thermal modifiers. I have also set the object temperature. But sadly I am not able to perform the simulations. Without temperatures, my simulations are working fine btw. Can someone please help me with that ?
I researched a little and found that ICEpack can predict temperatures. But the thing is, it predicts temperatures inside a material as a result of excitation i.e. how and where the temperatures will vary across the body as a result of excitation.
But what I am looking for is excitation at different temperatures, a very wide range at that and then study the results.
